# How can you view user timing data in Google Analytics split by URL?

Tags: google-analytics, performance, page-speed

Let's say I have a custom user timing in Google Analytics, which represents the time it takes for each page to load all the images above the fold (or a variety of other metrics). Since the images on each page are different, the average value for this across all pages isn't as useful for the average value for all samples on a specific URL or across pages which share a similar template.

The URL of the page each timing was collected from, doesn't appear to be an option under dimensions.

Is it possible to make a report that groups timings by URL or Content Group?

Answer (score 1):

To group by URL, you can select a secondary dimension of Page for URL.

To group by a Content Group, that should be a choice as a secondary dimension as well.

If you want more dimensions at once, create a custom report.